# How to index dates based on time interval

Tags: r, indexing

I am trying to figure out how to index orders placed within intervals of 120 days.

I have a dataframe:

```
customerid <- c("A1", "A1", "A1", "A1", "A1",  "A1", "A1", "A1", "A1", "A1", "A1", "A1", "A1", "A2", "A2", "A2")
orderid <- c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10","11","12","13","14","15","16")
orderdate <- c("2019-07-26", "2019-08-23", "2019-09-19", "2019-10-18", "2020-01-15", "2020-05-14","2020-06-09","2020-08-20", "2020-09-18", "2020-10-23", "2020-12-18", "2021-08-05", "2021-12-27", "2018-03-13", "2019-10-08", "2019-12-12")
df <- data.frame(customerid, orderid, orderdate)
```

For each customer, I want to group orders into intervals of 120 days and assign an index number to each group. The first order date is the first index date and I want to assign index_number == 1 to all subsequent orders that fall within 120 days of the 1st index date. Then, the 2nd index date is the earliest order date that does not fall in the first 120-day interval and I want to assign index_number == 2 to all subseuqent orders that fall within 120 days of the 2nd index date, and so forth until we run out of order dates.

The result should be:
[image]

Thank you!

**EDIT:** What if the orderdates were not in order from least to most recent? How would you sort them? And would the code change at all since we changed the data type? Thank you!

Comment: There appears to be no coding attempt we could help you with.

Comment: I am not sure where to start... I can do the above for the first index date (ie, group order dates between the minimum order date + 120 days), but I am not sure how to select for the 2nd index date and so on. Any help would be appreciated! Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using... loops!

Data:

```
customerid <- c("A1", "A1", "A1", "A1", "A1",  "A1", "A1", "A1", "A1", "A1", "A1", "A1", "A1", "A2", "A2", "A2")
orderid <- c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10","11","12","13","14","15","16")
orderdate <- c("2021-08-05", "2020-01-15", "2019-07-26", "2019-08-23", "2019-10-18", "2019-09-19", "2020-08-20", "2020-06-09","2020-09-18", "2020-10-23", "2020-05-14", "2020-12-18", "2021-12-27", "2019-10-08", "2018-03-13", "2019-12-12")
df <- data.frame(customerid, orderid, orderdate)
```

Transforming into date and sorting:

```
df$orderdate=as.Date(df$orderdate)
df=df[order(df$customerid,df$orderdate),]
```

Indexing:

```
i=1
idx=1
df$index=NA

for (j in 1:nrow(df)) {
  if (df$customerid[i]!=df$customerid[j]) {
    i=j
    idx=1
  }
  if (difftime(df$orderdate[j],df$orderdate[i],units="days")>120) {
    i=j
    idx=idx+1
  }
  df$index[j]=idx
}
```

resulting in

```
   customerid orderid  orderdate index
3          A1       3 2019-07-26     1
4          A1       4 2019-08-23     1
6          A1       6 2019-09-19     1
5          A1       5 2019-10-18     1
2          A1       2 2020-01-15     2
11         A1      11 2020-05-14     2
8          A1       8 2020-06-09     3
7          A1       7 2020-08-20     3
9          A1       9 2020-09-18     3
10         A1      10 2020-10-23     4
12         A1      12 2020-12-18     4
1          A1       1 2021-08-05     5
13         A1      13 2021-12-27     6
15         A2      15 2018-03-13     1
14         A2      14 2019-10-08     2
16         A2      16 2019-12-12     2
```

Answer (score 1):

A potential solution using my package `timeplyr`.

`time_mutate()` is like `mutate()` but accepts an additional `time` argument which lets you specify a date/datetime variable to aggregate.

**Note**: Basically the aggregation works by using unique time sequences for each group with each group's first date as the index date.

## Data prep

```r
# Uncomment the below to install
# remotes::install_github("NicChr/timeplyr")
library(lubridate)
library(timeplyr)
library(dplyr)
df <- df %>%
  mutate(orderdate = ymd(orderdate)) %>%
  arrange(customerid, orderdate) %>%
  group_by(customerid)
```

## Calculation

```r
df %>%
  time_mutate(time = across(orderdate, .names = "orderdate_agg"), by = "120 days") %>%
  mutate(id = consecutive_id(orderdate_agg))
#> # A tibble: 16 x 5
#> # Groups:   customerid [2]
#>    customerid orderid orderdate  orderdate_agg    id
#>    <chr>      <chr>   <date>     <date>        <int>
#>  1 A1         1       2019-07-26 2019-07-26        1
#>  2 A1         2       2019-08-23 2019-07-26        1
#>  3 A1         3       2019-09-19 2019-07-26        1
#>  4 A1         4       2019-10-18 2019-07-26        1
#>  5 A1         5       2020-01-15 2019-11-23        2
#>  6 A1         6       2020-05-14 2020-03-22        3
#>  7 A1         7       2020-06-09 2020-03-22        3
#>  8 A1         8       2020-08-20 2020-07-20        4
#>  9 A1         9       2020-09-18 2020-07-20        4
#> 10 A1         10      2020-10-23 2020-07-20        4
#> 11 A1         11      2020-12-18 2020-11-17        5
#> 12 A1         12      2021-08-05 2021-07-15        6
#> 13 A1         13      2021-12-27 2021-11-12        7
#> 14 A2         14      2018-03-13 2018-03-13        1
#> 15 A2         15      2019-10-08 2019-07-06        2
#> 16 A2         16      2019-12-12 2019-11-03        3
```

<sup>Created on 2023-05-03 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>